# Vaadin 6.7.7 and TreeTable component

Tags: java, vaadin, portlet, treetable

I have to use **Vaadin 6.7.7** version.

In particular, I have to use TreeTable Component that I see in vaadin example/tutoria.
But I can't to use this component in my project (Portlet with Vaadin 6.7.7).

The import

```
import com.vaadin.ui.TreeTable;
```

not work.
Is this component present in this Vaadin version?

Comment: yes `com.vaadin.ui.TreeTable` is available in vaadin 6.7.7 (found it via `vaadin.com/api` then select your desired version). Did you include the proper jar files. Is it a maven project? Can you show more information about your setup?

Comment: Also, is this the only vaadin class not found?

Comment: @geert3 I use Eclipse Luna and I create a Vaddin 6 Project as Portlet. I can see the vaadin jar in project lib folder (vaadin-6.7.7.jar). I can use other vaadin components like Table or Tree... but TreeTable not work. I can't to resolve the import. Can I get you some other info about my setup configuration?

Comment: All I can say is that Vaadin contains TreeTable as of 6.7.0 - Please have a look inside this jar. The class should be in there together with the other UI stuff. If it isn't perhaps it is another version incorrectly labelled. Perhaps check the manifest inside the jar. See also http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/v/Downloadvaadin677jar.htm